# Draw graph on uiview with animation

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiview, calayer, uiviewanimation

[image]

Hello Everyone,

I would like to create a similar view like in the attached image. I can do this easily with the help of UITableView but I also want to draw a graph above of this tableView. I am calculating some data and based upon that data (%), I have to draw my graph on that particular row(61-70 % etc). Also when the graph reaches into specific row, i need to start the timer of that particular row also. Can i draw a CALayer above of uitableView to achieve this? or i create a custom uiview with partition and draw graphs individually by creating CALayers. Please suggest. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a custom View and code init like 
@implementation CustomView

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame numberOfRows:(int)rows color:(NSArray *)colors
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    int yAxis =0;
    for(int i =0 ;i<[colors count];i++)
    {
        UIView *_v = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yAxis, 320, 480/rows)];
        [_v setBackgroundColor:[colors objectAtIndex:i]];
        [self addSubview:_v];

        /* add label and timer label according to your need */

    }

    return self;
}
```

then you can pass array of UIColors and number of rows.

Also for graph you need to check the origin value of graph.

Comment: Thanks deepak for the code lets say class A where i have created custom views, lets say it create 8 custom views with different colors one by one at the top. Now i have to draw the graph (ECG graph),should i use a CALayer above the mainViewcontroller to draw the graph?initial position of graph (x axis) wil be 0, but y axis can be dynamic, so based upon the y axis i have to draw the graph in the custom uiviews.The graph may come from top view to bottom view or rise from bottom to top. So what wil be the right approach to achieve it, As now i do have the frames(x,y) position of each custom views

Comment: It will look good if you start from bottom.As it will give a feel of rising graph to user.The best approach will be to keep it fix in the bottom and left.and keep the y axis dynamic along with the height.

Comment: I cannot restrict the graph to be start only from bottom, It may come from top also based upon the values received, I will manage to do so by calculating the frame position and generating the graphs on that particular custom uiview. but calling CGPathAddLineToPoint continuously to draw the graph will not decrease the performance of the app? Any other way to draw the paths into our custom uiviews?

Comment: Your answers are really helping me towards the right direction Thanks. I am trying to call from my mainView controller to the custom class like this Custom_Class *Obj = [[Custom_Class alloc] initWithFrame..... But no initialization option is coming up for the custom initializer (not initWithFrame), Should i use initWithCoder? If so then how should i pass the values of colorArray and number of rows in initWithcoder? Please guide

Comment: As you have just created a new custom initializer so you now need to use that only.

Declare your custom initializer in CustomView.h file and use that as code given below :
NSMutableArray *_colors =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    UIColor *_clr = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0];
    [_colors addObject:_clr];
    [_colors addObject:_clr];
    [_colors addObject:_clr];
    [_colors addObject:_clr];
    
    CustomView *_obj = [[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame numberOfRows:3 color:_colors];
    [self.view addSubview:_obj];

Comment: I am using it exactly same like you have mentioned but it is generating me this error :No visible @interface for 'Custom_View' declares the selector 'initWithFrame:numberOfRows:color:',

Comment: is it necessary to use the custom initializer to the superclass also, in order to call the custom class initializer "[[CustomView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame numberOfRows:3 color:_colors];" ?

Comment: I have solved the issue, I forgot to add the custom initializer in .h file so it was not calling from my main view Controller. thanks for the help deepak.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can tableview but my suggestion will be to use custom view as in that you can access any timer or startpoint as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But I would like to know that if i use custom UIView then how should i create the partitioned view according to the image i have attached with the question?

Comment: Create a UIView Subclass and declare init function like :
initWithNumberOfRows:(int)rows andColor:(NSArray *)color